# New Year's Predictions in Mathematics

Tags: soft-question

It is the time of year for predictions:
predictions for 2011, predictions for the next decade,
predictions for the unspecified future.
I searched a bit for predictions in mathematics,
but it seems mathematicians are too wise to engage in this
dubious activity.
I found only two predictions:

(1)
Two *New Scientist* writers, Samuel Arbesman and Rachel Courtland,
[predict that 2011 will *not* see the $P=NP$ problem resolved](http://www.newscientist.com/article/mg20827923.700).

(2)
Sir Michael Atiyah

> suggested that the conjectured self-adjoint operator that could explain
>   the Riemann hypothesis might be the Hamiltonian of quantum gravity

in a November talk at the [Simons Center](http://www.scgp.stonybrook.edu/), as [reported by Peter Woit](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~woit/wordpress/?p=3247).

Of course it is a stretch to call Atiyah's suggestion
a "prediction."  And every conjecture in mathematics is a prediction!
Nevertheless, in the spirit of New Year's, I would be interested
to hear any predictions on future developments in mathematics.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_of_mathematics

Comment: @Roy: Thanks, that is a nice collection; never thought to search Wikipedia for this type of information! 
As this link completely answers my question, it would be appropriate to close this question.

Comment: @Roy: I think that most of the opinions on that page are abhorrent where they pertain to pure mathematics and are irrelevant otherwise.

Comment: The Procrastinator's Club will soon release its predictions for 2010.  They have a history of complete accuracy.

Comment: I predict this question is going to be closed. 

Comment: No longer relevant?  It's only 8pm here in NY. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I've heard this type of prediction made:

In a few decades or so, the negation of the continuum hypothesis will be accepted as a consequence of some "obvious" axiom added to ZFC just as choice was added to ZF as an obvious axiom.

Comment: How long was this ago? One must be pretty much blind to say things like that nowadays...

Comment: @darij, would you care to elaborate?

Comment: @darij: This year; My use of obvious here is more of a technical nature.  The argument was that we've accepted the axiom of replacement because it is strongly used in proofs.  The proper forcing axiom, which implies $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_2$, is being advanced as an axiom to assume because of its many interesting and useful set-theoretical consequences including the existence of a Woodin cardinal in an inner model.  The argument is that eventually we'll just wind up accepting such an axiom as natural.

Comment: Algebraists used to "accept" additional axioms some time ago due to their use in putting category theory on a solid fundament (Grothendieck universes and the likes). Nowadays this seems to be a thing of the past, and modern algebraists have switched to more constructivist and type-theoretical approaches (even finitism is on the rise now). This is just my personal feeling from various talks by algebraists. Note that I am from Germany rather than from France, so maybe this Grothendieck school is still alive but I just never met it.