# f(2013) = 2014?

Tags: nt.number-theory, recreational-mathematics

I wonder if there is some "surprising" function $f(\;)$ that, when input $2013$, produces $2014$?
What I have in mind is more in
line with the Lewis Carroll computation involving $137$ and $992$ that Gerry Myerson
highlighted [in this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/153088/6094).
$f(n)=n+1$ would not satisfy. :-)

$$2013 = 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 61$$
$$2014 = 2 \cdot 19 \cdot 53$$
Hmmm...    Happy New Year!

Comment: but, $f(x) = x+1$ is the best approximation of the reality ;-)

Comment: $$f(x)=\begin{cases}2014 & 2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1\\x+1&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: 2013, 2014, and 2015 are all squarefree products of exactly 3 primes. They form the third smallest such trio, after the ones started with 1309 and 1885. See http://oeis.org/A165936 and see http://oeis.org/A167451 for another sequence in which 2013 is followed by 2014.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Thanks, Gerry---Exactly what I had in mind! but only a number aficionado could provide. :-)

Comment: Well, my historically 2nd (I think?) closed question, the other also [a failed attempt at New Year's bonhomie](http://mathoverflow.net/q/50826/6094). :-)

Comment: Along the lines of Gerry Myerson's comment:  how about defining $f(x)$ to be the least integer $n$ such that (1) $n>x$ and (2) $n$ and $x$ have the same number of prime factors?  Like Jan Dvorak's answer, this has the virtue of also working next year (though afterwards his seems to work somewhat better).